# change turing machine to RAM

Tags: formal-languages, turing-machines, computability, church-turing-thesis

How can we convert a given Turing Machine into a Random Access Machine? I understand that we can use the transition function to come up with a sort of algorithm but how can we translate all of it into a set of instructions (load/add etc).

For example, here's a TM:

```
M = ({q 0 , q 1 , q accept , q reject }, {0, 1}, {0, 1, t}, δ, q 0 , q accept , q reject )
```

having a transition function as follows:

[image]

Now, how can I formulate a set of RAM instructions from this?

Sample Solution:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can implement, on a RAM machine, an interpreter that simulates the behavior of an arbitrary Turing machine (that's just a matter of programming, and there's nothing conceptually interesting or difficult about it); then use it on this particular Turing machine.  That's much easier to do, but might not lead to nice code for the RAM machine.

Or, you can understand/reverse-engineer the algorithm the Turing machine is using (this could be difficult), and then figure out how to implement that algorithm on a RAM machine (which is just a matter of programming once you understand the algorithm).

Asking "how do I write code on a RAM machine?" is not very different from "how do I write code in assembly language?"; you just do it, and there's not a lot of deep scientific or conceptual ideas needed, once you know what algorithms you are using.

Comment: I added a snippet from the sample solution for this problem. I don't quite understand what we're loading and in what order. What exactly is 2 in c(o)=2. A brief explanation of the functionality would be nice.

Comment: @x89, That sounds tedious.  I suggest you work through those details yourself.  Perhaps run it by hand on some small examples.